# Group factors in scalar-gauge box diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, renormalization

So, I'm currently writing my Thesis, which involves one-loop beta functions of a general $SU(N)$ for scalars and fermions fields, Yukawa coupling and one scalar self-coupling.

To this moment I was able to find the gauge and Yukawa beta functions. However, for the scalar self-coupling $\lambda$, I'm struggling to get the $g^4$ correction, where $g$ is the gauge coupling.

I'm considering a box diagram involving 4 scalars external legs of same flavour and 2 "gluons" internal propagators and 2 scalars internal propagator, but the group factor and combinatorics is my issue. For reference, I'm trying to get the same result found at eq. (4.2) in https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/slacpubs/1250/slac-pub-1340.pdf.

Any help it'll be appreciate it.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.